# MSBuild ignores OutDir and always forces rebuild

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, rebuild, outdir

Our solution contains ~50 projects. They all import a custom .target file that sets the *OutDir* variable so that all projects build to a common *Binaries* folder.

Problem is: MSBuild does not check the *OutDir* folder for the .dlls but keeps looking inside the *OutputPath* folder (e.g. bin\Debug). As the *OutputPath* folder is empty it states that each project is not up-to-date and forces a rebuild. This is not an issue on our TFS build agents but it drastically increases the time between hitting F5 and the application starting on our development machines. Debugging becomes quite a pain.

From the *Binaries* folder we copy the .dlls to our applications folder structure which we use for generating setups etc. Thus simply dropping the use of *OutDir* in favor of various *OutputPaths* is not an option.

Is there any way to tell MSBuild to also check the *OutDir* folder when looking for existing .dlls?

Comment: @StevenLiekens Not really. We manually modified each and every *.csproj file to match the OutDir path in the end.

Comment: I'm doing the `OutDir` vs `OutputPath` dance right now. It seems to work at least partially as long as I set the properties before importing `Microsoft.CSharp.targets`.

Answer (score 0):

Following import in csproj files works for me in VS 2015. I added comments about which settings make it fail:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

      <PropertyGroup>
        <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
        <!-- to distinguish by $(Platform) does not work, a rebuild is triggered since the up-to-date check fails -->
        <!-- if IntermediateOutputPath is not set here at all, it does not work either, i.e. it always rebuilds -->
        <IntermediateOutputPath>$(SolutionDir)obj\$(Configuration)\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
        <UseCommonOutputDirectory>False</UseCommonOutputDirectory>
        <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>false</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(OutputType)' == 'Library' ">
        <!-- To distinguish by \lib\ does not work, a rebuild is triggered since the up-to-date check fails -->
        <!-- <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)bin\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)\lib\</OutputPath> -->
        <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)bin\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)</OutputPath>   
        <OutDir>$(OutputPath)</OutDir>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(OutputType)' == 'Exe' ">
        <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)bin\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)\</OutputPath>
        <OutDir>$(OutputPath)</OutDir>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Project>
```

The file is included in csproj files just before Import Microsoft.CSharp.targets:

.csproj file:

```
<!-- position of include is important, OutputType of project must be defined already -->
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)ComponentBuild.props" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)ComponentBuild.props')" /> 
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>
  </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Also see my own SO question about it: 
[MSBuild, OutputPath to a lib directory is not honoured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622866/msbuild-outputpath-to-a-lib-directory-is-not-honoured)